# UPDATE data table compare with another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two different table

info

```
------------------------
| no_ic_old |  name    |
------------------------
| 111111111 | John     |
------------------------
```

user

```
-------------------------------------
| no_ic_old |  name    |no_ic_new    |
--------------------------------------
| 111111111 | John     |222222222    |
--------------------------------------
```

i want to update info table so that it look like

```
------------------------
| no_ic_old |  name    |
------------------------
| 222222222 | John     |
------------------------
```

is there any ways to update that table using mysql?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the `name` column. Is it important that the values of the `name` column between the two tables match? What do we know about the uniqueness of the `no_ic_old` column, both in the `user` table and the `info` table? Some update statements we can propose will work for this specific example, but they won't necessarily "work" in the more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You want an `update` with a `join`:

```
update info i join
       user u
       on u.no_ic_old = i.no_ic_old
    set i.no_ic_old = u.no_ic_new;
```